# INVALID_EXTENSION using ng2 image tools

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am using ionic 2.

I retrieved images form firebase.

But i need resized this images.

Here is my function

```
var someImage:any="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/admin%2Fsample-1487416146311.jpg?alt=media&token=e61d2573-acd2-4284-b0b3-f45a1fc450cc";
     this.ng2ImgToolsService.resize([someImage], 100, 100).subscribe(result => {
            //all good, result is a file
            console.info(result);
        }, error => {
          console.log("err");
          console.log(error);
            //something went wrong 
            //use result.compressedFile or handle specific error cases individually
        })
```

I am getting this err.

How can i fixed this issue. or any other way to resize images

```
error:INVALID_EXTENSION

reason: "The provided File is neither of type jpg nor of type png."
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had faced the same issue I fixed this issue as shown below.

I had File called originalImage (obtained via a file Upload), i clone it to another File called modifieldImage

the code for the clone is as shown

```
const modifieldImage= new File(
          [uploadImage.originalImage],
          uploadImage.originalImage.name,
          {
            type: uploadImage.originalImage.type
          }
        );
//then call the api
this.ng2ImgMax .resizeImage(modifieldImage, 1600, 1176) ...
```

**try adding the 'type' while creating the File. That shold fix the issue.**

In your scenario, I believe the type of 'someImage' is empty. try cloning it to another File and adding the type in the FilePropertyBag

Hope it helps someone.